# the line <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> gives an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed Ruby and Rails, and all other things that are necessary, afaik.
I am on Windows 10, following the tutorial: 'http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html'

localhost:3000 is showing:

Showing C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/blog/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

TypeError: Deze eigenschap of methode wordt niet ondersteund door dit object
Rails.root: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/blog

Is there something that has to be installed, still?

I appreciate any help,
cheers,
Ad

Answer (score 0):

Did you install DEVELOPMENT KIT for your ruby version.
In windows it is compulsory to install devkit for run rails project.

If you didn't know about that please follow below link

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/